# How to split docx / pdf file pages in Laravel 9

Tags: php, ms-word, docx, laravel-9, phpword

I have an online library application that allows users to search the content of books by keywords.

To add a book to my application, I want to be able to upload the docx file of the book, then extract its content page by page, and add it to the database separately.
I couldn't find any specific library in Laravel/PHP to do that for me, so I tried to unzip the Docx file and look for a specific separator to detect pages based on that, but apparently, there is no such thing!

I even tried to read pages from the PDF file, but it returns weird characters that are not readable! I have to add the books are not written in English. They are written in Persian and Arabic which is a right-to-left language (please see bellow screenshot). Here is the link for a real data sample in pdf format: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g939q5oot14ib1w/test-for-stack-over-flow.pdf?dl=0.

Please let me know if you have any idea how can I add each page of the book to the database separately (as a new row in the pages table!), no matter what format I have to use, docx, pdf, txt, etc!

[image]

Comment: Thanks @KJ for your reply. I used dd() to see the output in the browser. The odd characters you see in the screenshot are the content I extracted from a pdf book for a page. I did the same for an English pdf book and that worked so that I could see the correct characters, but it is not working for pdf books in Persian. Do you mean I have to decode it first?

Comment: Hi @KJ and thank you for explaining that. Here is the link to a real data sample file in pdf format: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g939q5oot14ib1w/test-for-stack-over-flow.pdf?dl=0
Working with docx files was not easy for me and I couldn't find any separator for pages between the XML tags! So I prefer to work with pdf if I can find a way to extract the data from each page and add it to DB!

Comment: Do you mean the whole file is corrupted because of mojibake and so data cannot be extracted for any page of the pdf file? So how did you extract the above content(this one is correct انتشارات)?
That's okay for me even I can get 90% of the contents!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I am told that for word output to PDF then importing to MS Word is likely to give best results, but PHP itself is not an MSOffice User Workstation.

***Comments and installation feedback from @Kmaj ,are at the end.***

The closest I know is far from perfect but possibly can be bettered. So command line export PDF to plain text will look like this for the first page, where a number of issues with plain text become apparent, the major hurdle is word order can often be wrong at strategic input/output points.

 = symbolic characters like emojis [image]

[image]

So using Poppler PDFtotext gives this output for page 1 and the 1 can be in a loop from 1-100+.

```
pdftotext -nopgbrk -layout -f 1 -l 1 SO-75712922.pdf

‫انتشارات تست‪ /‬شمارۀ ‪53‬‬




‫کتاب تست‬
‫تست این کتاب‪‬‬



‫تست اصحاب‬
‫وصی و فرستادۀ ی‪‬‬

‫(خداوند در زمین تمکینش دهد)‬




‫مترجم‬
‫گروه مترجمان انتشارات تست ‪‬‬
```

And without -layout it should be more compact, but then Page 2 NEEDS it to be -Layout  to not encourage line splits. So documents like this are highly difficult to guess such that  output with layout and an alternative may need some automated selector for best of 2 or 3 runs.

**Page 1 without Layout** looks about 90% usable

[image]

**Page 2 with Layout** has the lines aligned for same height (but reversed order for tabular)
[image]

For windows users the 64 bit pre-compiled binaries (currently latest=2023-01) are at https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows

From @Kmaj **for Mac users**

> I first installed poppler on my mac using "brew install poppler". Then, I could successfully run the command you mentioned above in a loop and generate each txt page separately with a dynamic name.

> For those who have the same issue, I ran the following command in my mac terminal:

```
 for i in {1..3};
 do pdftotext-nopgbrk -layout -f ${i} -l ${i} ~/mypath-to-pdf/pdf-name.pdf ~/mypath-to-output-folder/output-name-${i}.txt;
 done
```

Comment: Thank you very much @K J for the time you spent on this issue. 
So I first installed poppler on my mac using "brew install poppler". Then, I could successfully run the command you mentioned above in a loop and generate each txt page separately with a dynamic name. For those who have the same issue, I ran the following command in my mac terminal:


for i in {1..3}; do pdftotext-nopgbrk -layout -f ${i} -l ${i} ~/mypath-to-pdf/pdf-name.pdf ~/mypath-to-output-folder/output-name-${I}.txt;  done

Comment: @K J, could you please include poppler installation and also the for loop command I mentioned above in your answer? Thanks

Comment: Thank you @KJ, that looks better now. Yes, that's a typo and it should be ${i} (lowercase).
I edited the topic by adding " / pdf" to cover pdf files too, not only docx.
The problem with this method is that many Persian/Arabic characters get corrupted. I am still looking for a way to extract the pages' text from the docx file because of the issue I mentioned above with pdf files

Comment: I tried that already, so I did unzip the docx file by PHP (laravel), but couldn't find any (XML tag) separator for pages so that I can extract each page's content and insert it into DB in a loop. I tried many solutions that I found on the Internet, but the output was always wrong! For example, if the docx file has 10 pages, I always get more pages (15 to 25 pages) because of the page breaks! I even tried to find the separator of the page numbers to separate pages based on that but had no luck on that too!